# PHP PDO: Unable to connect, Invalid catalog name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mysqli

I am trying to set up a new site on my hosting (Host route if it matters) but i keep getting this error when i try using PDO (first PDO site im trying):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' in /home/kennyi81/public_html/gamersite/login.php:36 Stack trace: #0 /home/kennyi81/public_html/gamersite/login.php(36): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/kennyi81/public_html/gamersite/login.php on line 36
```

When i use these settings:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:91.146.107.11;dbname=kennyi81_gamersite", "kennyi81_gamer", "***************");
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

....

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = :id LIMIT 1');
```

How the database is laid out:

[image]

I am able to use mysqli connect fine on my other sub domains / main site, but i just cannot get PDO to work.

I've tried this, which i have seen around:

```
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM gamersite.USERS WHERE ID = :id LIMIT 1');
```

but it retuns a syntax error.

Anyone have any idea what may be causing this?

---

This is all working on my local server, nothing changed on upload apart from connect line.

Comment: new PDO("mysql:host=91.146.107.11

Comment: @Mike Its the $stmt->execute(); for the query shown above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:91.146.107.11;dbname=kennyi81_gamersite", "kennyi81_gamer", "***************");
```

Try:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=91.146.107.11;dbname=kennyi81_gamersite", "kennyi81_gamer", "***************");
```

(add **host=**)

And it most likely works on your local server, because you have `mysql:localhost...` or `mysql:127.0.0.1...` there and it's ignored (cause it's missing **host=** aswell) and by default it's localhost.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PDO manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php), you can see that you need to wrap the connection in a `try/catch` block. This way if something goes wrong with the connection, it will tell you. Something like this:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:91.146.107.11;dbname=kennyi81_gamersite", "kennyi81_gamer", "***************");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";

    // Then actually do something about the error
    logError($e->getMessage(), __FILE__, __LINE__);
    emailErrorToAdmin($e->getMessage(), __FILE__, __LINE__);
    // etc.
    die(); // Comment this out if you want the script to continue execution
}
```

The reason you are getting this error is because there is an error with your connection, but since you don't tell your script to stop, it doesn't. Look at the error message produced, and how to fix it should be made obvious. It appears that Michael Prajsnar's answer is correct in that you aren't setting a "host".

**Edit:**

As it turns out, PDO **doesn't** complain if you leave out your `host` or `dbname` in the PDO connection DSN part (at least on Unix). I tested it and leaving it blank will default it to "localhost" and I was therefore able to connect perfectly fine leaving this out completely for localhost connections, which would explain why it worked on your local server but not on your production server. In fact, it is completely possible to connect supplying absolutely nothing in the DSN except for the database engine like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:", "kennyi81_gamer", "***************");
```

The only problem is that it won't be using a database, so to USE a database, just do:

```
if ($dbh->query("USE kennyi81_gamersite") === false)) {
     // Handle the error
}
```

However with that said, **I have my doubts** that you actually tried connecting using a `try/catch` block (as you mention in your comments) unless you somehow provided valid database credentials. The ONLY way that doing it this way did not produce any sort of error is if you actually connected correctly and selected the database `kennyi81_gamersite`. If not, you would have seen a message like this:

> Unable to connect to database. "mysql" said: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045]
>   Access denied for user 'kennyi81_gamer'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

In summary, always wrap your connection in a `try/catch` block if you want to find errors during connection. Just make sure not to re-throw (and not catch) the `PDOException`'s `getMessage()` or you could expose your login credentials.

Comment: I tried that but no message ever appeared apart from the one i already got.

Comment: Leaving an exception uncaught will also *tell you* as well as trigger a fatal error, thus stopping further execution. This trend of advising developers to catch exceptions and only print out the message seems to be PHP's next round of terrible advice

Comment: @Phil Good point. I just took the example from [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php). Of course, you could do whatever you want while catching the error. I've updated my answer to reflect that.