# SQLSTATE[3D000]:1046 - No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was trying to execute a SQL CREATE command with php but I have this problem:

> SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

I REALLY can't know where is the problem, please could you help me?

This is the script:

```
<?php

include 'connessione.php';

try {
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE joke (
            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            joketext TEXT,
            jokedate DATE NOT NULL 
            ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET uft8 ENGINE=InnoDB';
    $pdo->exec($sql);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    $output = 'Errore nella creazione della tabella joke: ' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}

$output = 'Tabella creata con successo.';
include 'output.html.php';

?>
```

And here the "connessione.php" file:

```
<?php

$host = 'host=localhost'; 
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_password = '';
$database = 'php';

try { 
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:$host;dbname=$database', $mysql_user, $mysql_password); 
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $output = 'Impossibile connettersi al database: ' . $e->getmessage();
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}

?>
```

I checked the "connessione.php" file and the connection to database is right. Also, I checked user privileges and root has all privileges to "php" database... What's the problem?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problematic line is the connection itself:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:$host;dbname=$database'
```

Remember that this is a string literal since they are wrapped with single quotes.

Change them you double quotes if you want the variables interpolated.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:$host;dbname=$database", $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
```

Answer (score 0):

It LOOKS like you're missing "host=" when you create the db handle. I'd also recommend searching SO or Google before asking questions - tons of hits for this issue: [PHP PDO: Unable to connect, Invalid catalog name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499054/php-pdo-unable-to-connect-invalid-catalog-name)

Comment: Yes but... What I did wrong with variables?

Comment: And also... Why if I do only the connection it is all right and if I use the same connection code to create a table it is wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, I did not see you set "host=" in the variable - that's a weird convention. I'd move the "host=" part to the statement where you create the handle and leave the variable as value "localhost". Easier to debug and easier to change if need be. How do you know the connection is made? I don't see a statement or anything confirming it, so how are you sure? Try echoing out your variables to see if they do contain what you think they do.

Comment: Well, I'm sure because before to write the script to create a table the file "connessione.php" has (after the exception):

$output = 'connection established';
include 'output.html.php';

Comment: Also: If I set "host=" in the statement the connection doesn't done!